# Mailer not working on column update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, mailchimp

I currently have a mailer sending out an email every time I change the column balance for a user via my admin platform at adminium. I can change the column via Adminium and it saves it just fine and changes it in the DB but the email doesn't send.

User.rb

```
  after_update :balance_has_changed?

  def balance_has_changed?
    if balance_changed?
      # balance
      # balance_was
      # send an email!
      UserMailer.balance_changed(self, balance, balance_was).deliver
    end
  end

  handle_asynchronously :balance_has_changed?
```

UserMailer

```
  def balance_changed(user, new_balance, old_balance)
    mandrill_mail(
        template: 'balance_changed',
        subject: 'New Earnings through Bundel!',
        to: { email:user.email },
        vars: {
            'OLD_BALANCE' => old_balance,
            'NEW_BALANCE' => new_balance
        }
    )
  end
```

Using Mandrill with Mailchimp - template is all uploaded to Mandrill so no errors that side.

Any help would be brilliant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How similar / different is Adminium from gems such as rails_admin or active_admin ? It is similar in purpose to rails_admin and
>   active_admin.
>
> It is however different in how it operates and thus allows different
>   things. Rails admin and active admin are gems to be used with a Rails
>   3 application whereas Adminium is an Heroku add-on which can be used
>   with any Heroku application, no matter the Rails version, the
>   framework or even the language.
>
> It also differs in the way it is configured ; rails / active admin use
>   DSLs and thus require to write code and deploy the application to
>   modify the configuration of the admin, whereas all the configuration
>   in Adminium is done via the interface independently of the lifecycle
>   of the target application and also allowing non technical users to be
>   in charge of it

This does not integrate with your rails app and will not trigger rails callbacks.

This is what it's doing:
Adminium -> Database

Not this:
Adminium -> Rails -> Database

https://www.adminium.io/docs

You could write a rails rake task that checks to see if a column has changed and send out emails. You might need a cached column or something.